# Gridview.Sort doesn't sort anything?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm loading a gridview like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateAll();
}

private void PopulateAll()
{
    DataTable dt = GetSqlTableAsDataTable(_query);
    gv_priorities.DataSource = dt;
    gv_priorities.Sort("MyColumnHeader", System.Web.UI.WebControls.SortDirection.Ascending);
    gv_priorities.DataBind();
}
```

The sort event is processed, it will fire the `OnSorting` and `OnSorted` event if I include them, but why doesn't it actually sort the data? I understand I can sort in the datatable, but why does `GridView.Sort()` not work?

My gridview has a simple setup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server"
    ID="gv_priorities"
    AllowSorting="true"
    OnSorted="gv_priorities_Sorted"
    OnSorting="gv_priorities_Sorting"
    AllowPaging="true"
    PageSize="20"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gv_priorities_PageIndexChanging">
    <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Oh wait.. do I have to bind it first... no, that doesn't help.

Comment: What is the type of  `MyColumnHeader`?

Comment: I've tried string and numericals, nothing seems to work

Comment: Move you page load code inside !page.ispostback check. Your problem is that your gridview is binding on each postback.

Comment: How about if you put `PopulateAll()` in `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`?

Comment: I have already suggested that.

Comment: But the sorting happens IN the `PopulateAll()` routine. I want it to be sorted on the very first page load...

Comment: Is it because it's bound data? Does it simply not work with bound data? The example I see on MSDN is using an in-line DataSourceId but I don't want to use that... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort?view=netframework-4.8#:~:text=Use%20the%20Sort%20method%20to%20programmatically%20sort%20the%20GridView%20control,separated%20list%20of%20field%20names.

Comment: Did you implement the event handlers `gv_priorities_Sorted` and `gv_priorities_Sorting`? I guess you should add the `Sort()` codes besides the `gv_priorities_Sorting`.

Comment: If I put the `Sort` inside the `Sorting` event then it gets stuck in an infinite loop. If put a cancel flag on there it ends up doing nothing. I just think it doesn't work with bound data at all, it needs to have an inline data source. So, I gave up and used `DataTable dt = GridView.DataSource` then sort the dt.defaultview and rebind to the gridview. It's annoying because I have to convert the enum sort expressions to strings etc.